# How to make my bot respond when it us mentioned discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot respond when it is pinged, so if someone doesn't know the prefix, he can simply ping the bot and he will reply with the prefix. I've tried several ways of doing it, but it either didn't respond at all, or it started spamming the same message over and over. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content.includes('<@744284134397968425>')) {
    message.reply(`my prefix here is ${prefix}`)
    return
  };
});
```

Didn't respond at all (the ID is right)

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.mentions.has(client.user)) {
    message.reply(`my prefix here is ${prefix}`)
    return
  };
});
```

Didn't respond at all, and yes, I have the bot set as client.

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.mentions.has(client.user.id)) {
    message.reply(`my prefix here is ${prefix}`)
    return
  };
});
```

And that kept spamming the channel. I didn't get any errors and/or crashes when it didn't respond.
How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, as I said, it spams the channel if I use the accepted answer, if I use the 2nd one, it doesn't respond

Comment: Are you sure you are checking if the message's author is a bot account?

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking at the [`MessageMentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) Collection.

```js
if (message.mentions.users.has(client.user.id) && !message.author.bot) {
  message.reply(`my prefix here is ${prefix}`)
  return
};
```

Comment: It still spams the channel

Comment: It might be because the bot is triggering the message event and initiating a loop. See my edited answer

Comment: Even with that modification it keeps spamming the channel @Lioness100